# How to fixed upload page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Currently I have upload page  which are targeted to API URL, as tested the API is working. However, from Front End side the file is not reflect to Database when user click button. I didn't whether my JS code below is working or not. May someone give an advice.

```html
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="upload_file" id="abc" class="import-file">
</div>

<div class="padding-bottom-30 row" style="max-width: 170px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="col-6">
    <button type="button" id="btnNo" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
      NO
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <button type="button" id="btnYes" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
      YES
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#btnYes").on("click", function() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  var files = $('#abc')[0].files[0];
  fd.append('upload_file', files);

  console.log(files);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'XXX',
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
      if (response != 0) {
        $('#success-upload').modal('show');
      } else {
        alert('File Format Not Supported');
      }
    },
  });
});

$("#success-upload").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $('#abcTables').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

Comment: Check the console to ensure your JS is working, and check your server side logs to make sure the file saving logic is working. If you see any errors in either of those please edit the question to include them

Comment: in jquery you select `btnYes` but this id doesn't exist in the HTML you posted. Can you please post the relevant HTML which contains said ID?